# IAM role connectivity between Lambda and Mongo Atlas Serverless using AWS SAM

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, mongodb-atlas

**Problem Statement**

I am currently attempting to establish a connection with MongoDB using the IAM Role as described [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/passwordless-authentication/) . The problem statement is that I am unsure of the process required to ensure the connection works from an AWS perspective using Lambda.

**Background info**

I've created an IAM Role using AWS SAM.

```
MongoDBReadWriteAccess:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: MongoDBReadWriteAccess
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: arn:aws:iam::<atlast aws account ID>:root
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                sts:ExternalId: <external ID>
```

I  attempt to retrieve the  keys from the env variables in my application logic

```
 aws_access_key_id = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
 aws_secret_access_key = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
 aws_session_token = os.getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN")
```

I create the connection

```
url_connection = f"mongodb+srv://{access_key_URI}:{secret_key_URI}@{server_name}.ozmat.mongodb.net/?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-AWS&retryWrites=true&w=majority&authMechanismProperties=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN:{session_token_URI}"
```

However the role that I created isn't the assumed role at execution time.

```
 OperationFailure: bad auth : user arn:aws:sts::<id>:assumed-role/<incorrect_role_name>/* is not found, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : user arn:aws:sts::<id>:assumed-role/<incorrect_role_name> is not found', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
                                Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I've attempted to assign the role using SAM

```
StepPlanCRUD:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Role: !GetAtt MongoDBReadWriteAccess.Arn
```

but I get the following error on deploy:

```
"The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, ...
```

Please can somebody detail the steps required in order to allow connectivity between Lambda and Atlas from an AWS perspective?

Answer (score 0):

First assign policy for lambda that allows to assume MongoDBAtlas role that you have created

E.g.

```
    PolicyName: AssumeMongoDBReadWriteAccessRole
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Effect: Allow
        Resource: 
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - MongoDBReadWriteAccess
            - Arn
      Version: 2012-10-17
```

Then, inside lambda code, use AWS CLI command `aws sts assume-role` to assume that role and retrieve keys (AccessKeyID, SecretAccessKey, SessionToken). Now you can use them to open a connection.